# How user stake and earn reward and How we can implement this staking model

Tags: eosio-code, staking, eosio.system, unstake, system-accounts

Basically, staking and unstaking are an on going process throughout the life of a blockchain and in EOSIO we have

1. 0.1 token not 10% of the account's tokens is staked for RAM
2. Cleos stakes 8 KB of RAM on account creation paid by the account creator
3. 0.45 token is staked for CPU
4. 0.45 token is staked for network

   **My question is, is it possible user stake and earn reward without using CPU and RAM**

***as one of the main issues in EOSIO based blockchains today is the cost of using the network and CPU resources.***

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand fully your question, however here's an attempt at answering it. Any interaction with a smart contract's actions [requires sufficient resources](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosio.contracts/latest/key-concepts/stake/#how-to-allocate-system-resources) for those actions to start and finish successfully.
when you stake, you interact with a smart contract therefore someone needs to pay for the execution of staking action.